# How to get documents checking against a permissions junction table with query builder in symfony doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm curious how to build a doctrine query with query builder in Symfony which can exclude items based on a fairly standardized permissions junction table.

In my case,

`User` entity

`Template` entity

`userTemplatePermissionTable`

In userTemplatePermissions Entity, we have the following properties:

`userToCheck`, `template`, `read`, `write`, `delete`

And I'd like something the equivalent of:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
[where count of t.userDocumentPermissions > 0
  where canRead = true, canWrite = true, canDelete = true
AND userDocumentpermissions.user = :user]
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a fairly simple setup of left joins and exclusion checks, I wound up with the following in my `TemplateRespository.php`

```
public function findUserAuthorized($user, $read = null, $write = null, $delete = null)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->leftJoin('t.userTemplatePermissions', 'utp')
    ->where('utp.userToCheck = :user')
    ->setParameter('user',$user);

    if ($read !== null) {
        $query->andWhere('utp.read = :read')
        ->setParameter('read',$read);
    }
    if ($write !== null) {
        $query->andWhere('utp.write = :write')
        ->setParameter('write',$write);
    }
    if ($delete !== null) {
        $query->andWhere('utp.delete = :delete')
        ->setParameter('delete',$delete);
    }
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```